# Zoom DIV Effect, Weird Behaviour when Hovering Fast

Tags: jquery, hover, zooming

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/8fvJN/15/

I am getting a very weird effect when you hover from one box to the next in quick succession - they start going kind of mad.  Try hovering from one to the other very fast, and you will see what I mean.

Is there any way to stop this behaviour?

Zach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
.stop(true, true)
```

It will clear the queue and stop the current animation.

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8fvJN/84/)